# Incorporating dictionary elements within Jinja2 If/elif statement

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm having trouble rendering dictionary data with Jinja2.

I have two different dictionary variables. `cinfo['cbs']`holds data from user input. I was able to render that data. The other is located within `pdata`, though I haven't been able to render this data.

The text will render under the `".leftcell"` `td`, but the data on the `".rightcell"` `td` appears empty. I would like the jinja to skip the block completely if both dictionary variables hold blank strings.

For context- here is my stream command:

```
template.stream(cinfo=cinfo,  pdata = pdata)
```

The following is the "pdata" dictionary data structure:

```
pdata = {'Building Size': {'Data': '28,106 SF'}}
```

and the following is my jinja2 code:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body lang="en-US">
  <div id="propertyinfo">
    <table id="pitable" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>


        {% if cinfo['cbs'] != "" %}
        <tr>
          <td class="leftcell">
            Building Size
          </td>
          <td class="rightcell">
            {{cinfo['cbs']}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% elif pdata["Building Size"]["Data"] != "" %}
        <tr>
          <td class="leftcell">
            Building Size
          </td>
          <td class="rightcell">
            {{pdata["Building Size"]["Data"]}}
          </td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: You haven't shown the `jinja` loop... `{% if cinfo['cbs'] != "" %}` has no context in relation to your code. You don't have a `cbs` key.

Comment: I defined what `cbs` means in the post- it is a dictionary storing user input data- if the user does not enter text it should hold a blank string. The if statement itself is located within a fairly large HTML table, not a loop

Comment: Either I'm going blind or you haven't defined `cbs` in your post.

Comment: cinfo['cbs'] is what I meant- sorry. Either way, I was able to render cinfo['cbs'] in a different test, but pdata is the dictionary that does not display

Comment: You've shown something that you're sending back to be rendered but I can't fit the pieces together. I think it needs clarifying.

Comment: I've just added my template stream command and defined pdata explicitly. does that make more sense?

Comment: Certainly, on my phone, I don't think I can fix this. I've been abrupt, but no hard feelings intended, sorry. If you remove yourself from the problem and re-read the question, I'm not sure it makes sense. It could just be me, but I'm not getting it

Comment: Just added an abbreviated version of the entire html I am trying to render if that helps. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try
pdata as follows, only to avoid blankspace

```
pdata = {'Building_Size': {'Data': '28,106 SF'}}
```

and access to dict content with "."

```
  {% if cinfo.cbs != "" %}
  <tr>
                <td class="leftcell">
                    Building Size
                </td>
                <td class="rightcell">
                    {{cinfo.cbs}}
                </td>
            </tr>
  {% elif pdata.Building_Size.Data != "" %}
  <tr>
                <td class="leftcell">
                    Building Size
                </td>
                <td class="rightcell">
                    {{pdata.Building_Size.Data}}
                </td>
            </tr>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry- I tried accessing the dict content with "." but received the following error: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '_Size'`